# Converting string into datetime: ValueError in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

i check many **StackOverflow** questions. But can't solve this problem...

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import csv

username = input("enter name: ")
with open('../data/%s_tweets.csv' % (username), 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)

for x in your_list:
    date = x[1] # is the date index
    dateOb = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
    # i also used "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S" formate
    # i also used "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S" formate
    # i also used "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S%p" formate
    # but the same error shows for every formate
    print(dateOb)
```

i am getting the error

```
ValueError: time data 'date' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S'
```

[in my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Q41.png)

Comment: There is no problem with your format, it seems that the variable `date`  is not what you've added here.

Comment: i can't understand your answer.. what should i do now @Kasramvd ??

Comment: It means that when we run the code you've included, it works fine for us. Make sure your code does in fact look like the above, otherwise share what code you're actually using.

Comment: oo sry for the confusion,....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ValueError: time data 'date' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S'`

*'date'* is not a Date String.
That's why python can not convert this string into DateTime format. 
I check in my .csv file, and there i found the 1st line of the date list is not a date string, is a column head.
I remove the first line of my CSV file, and then its works in *Python 3.5.1*.
But, sill the same problem is occurring in *python 2.7*

Comment: always check your data files before using it. will u !